# Stop opening a Form multiple times

Tags: vb.net

There is a dynamically added `MenuStrip` in my application, in which each menu opens a `Form`. When the user clicks the menu item it opens a new `Form` each time. I want to stop opening a `Form` if it is already open. Image attached, in which every time open a new `Form` when clicking on the menu item.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.IsMdiContainer = True
    mnuStrip = New MenuStrip() 'create the object
    Me.Controls.Add(mnuStrip)

    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLExpress,1433;Initial Catalog=MENUDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=EZ@123&*")

    Dim sql As String = "select MenuID, MenuName from Menu_Details"
    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    sda.Fill(dt)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        mnuStripItem = New ToolStripMenuItem(dr("MenuName").ToString())
        SubMenu(mnuStripItem, dr("MenuID").ToString())
        mnuStrip.Items.Add(mnuStripItem)
    Next
    Me.MainMenuStrip = mnuStrip
End Sub

Public Sub SubMenu(mnu As ToolStripMenuItem, mainMenuID As String)
    Dim SqlQuery2 As String = ("select SubMenuName from [SubMenu_Details] where MenuID='") & mainMenuID + "'"
    Dim sdaSqlQuery2 As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery2, con)
    Dim dtSqlQuery2 As New DataTable()
    sdaSqlQuery2.Fill(dtSqlQuery2)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dtSqlQuery2.Rows
        Dim ssmenu As New ToolStripMenuItem(dr("SubMenuName").ToString(), Nothing, New EventHandler(AddressOf MenuClick))
        mnu.DropDownItems.Add(ssmenu)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MenuClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sqlFormName As String = "select Form_Name,SubMenuName from [SubMenu_Details] where SubMenuName='" + sender.ToString() + "'"
    Dim sdaFormName As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlFormName, con)
    Dim dtFormName As New DataTable()
    sdaFormName.Fill(dtFormName)

    Dim frmAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.ExecutablePath)
    For Each type As Type In frmAssembly.GetTypes()
        If type.BaseType = GetType(Form) Then
            If type.Name = dtFormName.Rows(0)(0).ToString Then
                Dim frmshow As Form = DirectCast(frmAssembly.CreateInstance(type.ToString()), Form)
                frmshow.MdiParent = Me
                frmshow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                frmshow.Text = dtFormName.Rows(0)(1).ToString
                frmshow.Show()
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: 1]

Comment: If the type that you are about to add is already exist in the mdi parent [MdiChildren](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren?view=windowsdesktop-8.0), then don't add it. Also, keep that `DataTable` in a class field, avoid running dbass queries this way. Alternatively, disable the menu item when you add the corresponding `Form`. Enable it again when you close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the forms you already have in a dictionary. This works when you want single instances of all forms loaded in this manner.

```vb
Dim forms As New Dictionary(Of String, Form)()
```

```vb
Dim frmshow As Form
If forms.ContainsKey(type.ToString()) Then
    frmshow = forms(type.ToString())
Else
    frmshow = DirectCast(frmAssembly.CreateInstance(type.ToString()), Form)
    forms.Add(type.ToString(), frmshow)
    AddHandler frmshow.FormClosed, AddressOf formClosedHandler
    frmshow.MdiParent = Me
    ' optionally move this out of the Else
    frmshow.Text = dtFormName.Rows(0)(1).ToString
End If
' optionally move this into the Else
frmshow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
frmshow.Show()
```

Also handle the closing event so you can remove the form from the dictionary

```vb
Private Sub formClosedHandler(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    Dim f = DirectCast(sender, Form)
    If forms.ContainsValue(f) Then
        forms.Remove(forms.Single(Function(x) x.Value Is f).Key)
        RemoveHandler f.FormClosed, AddressOf formClosedHandler
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Example, an app with two forms.  The main form(MainForm) will create just one sub form(SubForm ) at a time.

```
Public Class MainForm
    Private OtherForm As SubForm 'the second form in my app
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If OtherForm Is Nothing OrElse Not Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of SubForm).Any Then
            OtherForm = New SubForm
            OtherForm.Show()
        Else
            OtherForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            OtherForm.BringToFront()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm generally against the use of default instances but they do act as a singleton, so they can be useful in the situation where you want just one instance of a form. They also automatically create a new instance when the previous one has been disposed, so they simplify code significantly. You can simply put code like this in whatever event handler is supposed to display the form:

```vb
SomeForm.Show()
SomeForm.Activate()
```

In this case, `SomeForm` is the class itself, not a variable of that type. The first line will create and display an instance if one is not already displayed. The second line will ensure that the form has focus if it was already displayed. You can put any other code before that if you want to modify the instance in some way, e.g. it looks like you're displaying an MDI child form, so you can do this:

```vb
SomeForm.MdiParent = Me
SomeForm.Show()
SomeForm.Activate()
```

That's not going hurt an existing instance at all.

Answer (score 1):

As it appears you have a parent form (MDI, maybe?), you can track instances of each form. For example, suppose you want only one instance of `ProductMaintenanceForm` open at one time. You can put this code in the parent/MDI form that has the menu options to show the other forms.

```
Private _productMaintenanceForm as ProductMaintenanceForm

Private Sub PutThisCodeInYourMenuEventHandler

    ' Put this code in the event handler of the Button/ToolStripButton/MenuItem event handler that shows the form.
    If _productMaintanceForm Is Nothing Then
        _productMaintenaceForm = New ProductMaintenanceForm
        _productMaintenanceForm.Show()
    Else
        _productMainteanceForm.Focus
    End If

End Sub
```